# Awkward group by with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an events database that contains events and orders customers have made to buy tickets for those events.

I need a query that will return a list of customers who have an upcoming event and to know what the next event they're going to is.

So after a few joins I can get this kind of output:

```
CustomerNo | PerformanceDate  | EventName
1234       | 2016-07-01 19:00 | Phantom of the Opera
2345       | 2016-06-01 19:00 | The sound of music
1234       | 2016-06-01 19:00 | The sound of music
```

i.e. a list of all customers with an upcoming event but it contains all their upcoming events whereas I just want the next one e.g.

```
CustomerNo | PerformanceDate  | EventName
2345       | 2016-06-01 19:00 | The sound of music
1234       | 2016-06-01 19:00 | The sound of music
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably something like this:

```
SELECT t.CustomerNo, PerformanceDate, EventName
FROM TableName t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerNo, Min(PerformanceDate) As MinDate
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY CustomerNo
) g ON(t.CustomerNo = g.CustomerNo AND t.PerformanceDate = g.MinDate)
```

You can also use a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) instead of the derived table:

```
;With cte as
(
    SELECT CustomerNo, Min(PerformanceDate) As MinDate
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY CustomerNo
)

SELECT t.CustomerNo, PerformanceDate, EventName
FROM TableName t
INNER JOIN cte ON(t.CustomerNo = cte.CustomerNo AND t.PerformanceDate = cte.MinDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact a lot of SQL is much simpler in SQL Server :)

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNo
            ORDER BY PerformanceDate) AS rn
   FROM TableName
   WHERE PerformanceDate > NOW()
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1
```